# MIPS Programming in Past Paper

Tags: mips

I'm very confused about a question in a university past paper. It is as follows:

What is the value in register $s1 after executing the following piece of MIPS
assembly code?

```
      li $t0, 0x1
      li $s0, 0x0
      li $s1, 0xa5a5a5a5
loop: and $t1, $t0, $s1
      beq $t1, $zero, skip
      addi $s0, $s0, 1
skip: sll $t0, $t0, 1 # Shift left logical
      bne $t0, $zero, loop
```

(a) 0x10

(b) 0xa5a5a5a5

(c) 0x0

(d) 0x5a5a5a5a

(e) 0x1

The given answer is A - now, as far as I'm aware, the value of $s1 is not changed after its initial declaration - so how is this the case? I'd have thought it would be B?

Comment: Yes, the given answer is B because, `$s1` only used to make an `and` operation between `$s1` and `$t0`, `$s1` is not changed .

Comment: Realised I did something silly - the given 'correct' answer is actually A. Surely it must be B though, right?

Comment: Perhaps it was a typo in the exam and the question was supposed to ask for the final value of `$s0` (which looks like it would be 0x10)?

Answer (score 0):

This shows the QTSpim:

[image]

This shows the PCSpim:

[image]